# In JMeter Java MD5 hashing function not always has a right hush

Tags: java, jmeter, md5

In Jmeter, I am trying to generate a Token for loading Mapi, but the token does not always have the desired length.  One test token is:
"b7d5cd060b01289825e0ec1f6b126ca", another one is
"de8520a143583f1239b95bcc02b36eeb".

The second one is longer by 1 character.

my function:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.math.BigInteger;

long str = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
String Timestamp = Long.toString(str);
//System.out.println(Timestamp);




String seconds2 = str + "8fo9aw8uefawejfoi";
MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
md5.update(seconds2.getBytes());
BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md5.digest());
String Token = hash.toString(16);
//System.out.println(Token);

vars.put("Timestamp", Timestamp);  
vars.put("Token", Token)
```

Comment: Why don't you make a recursive function to generate Token which will check if length is 16, and if it's false repeat the process, and if it's true put the Token into variable?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding my comment on question... Try using this in Beanshell:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.math.BigInteger;

private void TokenGeneration(Long s) {
    String seconds2 = String.valueOf(str) + "8fo9aw8uefawejfoi";
    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md5.update(seconds2.getBytes());
    BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, md5.digest());
    String Token = hash.toString(16);
    if (Token.length() == 32)
        vars.put("Token", Token);
    else 
        TokenGeneration(s);
}

long str = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
String Timestamp = Long.toString(str);
vars.put("Timestamp", Timestamp); 

TokenGeneration(str);
```

Comment: Thank u very much for such quick answer!
I used java (Beanshell), but Token didnt generate.. :(

Comment: Stupid mistake... :-) I have length check at 16, it will never be 16! :-) Just replace with your desired length, I will edit to 32. Sorry mate!